# Getting features in RFECV scikit-learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cross-validation, rfe

Inspired by this: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/feature_selection/plot_rfe_with_cross_validation.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-feature-selection-plot-rfe-with-cross-validation-py

I am wondering if there is anyway to get the features for a particular score:

[image]

In that case, I would like to know, which 10 features selected gives that peak when #Features = 10.

Any ideas?

EDIT:

This is the code used to get that plot:

```
from sklearn.feature_selection import RFECV
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold,StratifiedKFold #for K-fold cross validation
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier #Random Forest

# The "accuracy" scoring is proportional to the number of correct classifications
#kfold = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=10, random_state=1) # k=10, split the data into 10 equal parts
model_Linear_SVM=svm.SVC(kernel='linear', probability=True)
rfecv = RFECV(estimator=model_Linear_SVM, step=1, cv=kfold,scoring='accuracy')   #5-fold cross-validation
rfecv = rfecv.fit(X, y)

print('Optimal number of features :', rfecv.n_features_)
print('Best features :', X.columns[rfecv.support_])
print('Original features :', X.columns)
plt.figure()
plt.xlabel("Number of features selected")
plt.ylabel("Cross validation score \n of number of selected features")
plt.plot(range(1, len(rfecv.grid_scores_) + 1), rfecv.grid_scores_)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Could you please add the code that produced this figure?

Comment: @VladislavGladkikh added

Comment: You first need to make the process reproducible by setting the param random_state in everywhere you can find it. After that, you can extend the RFECV `fit()` method to print the features at each time

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First, you can see which features it selected where the cross validation score is the largest (in your case this corresponds to the number of features 17 or 21, I am not sure from the figure) with

```
rfecv.support_
```

or

```
rfecv.ranking_
```

Then you can calculate the importances of selected features (for the peak of the cv score curve) by

```
np.absolute(rfecv.estimator_.coef_)
```

for simple estimators or

```
rfecv.estimator_.feature_importances_
```

if your estimator is some ensemble, like random forest.

Then you can remove the least important feature one by one in the loop, and recalculate rfecv for the remaining feature sets.