# How to interpret importance of features from _coeffs outputs for multi-class in sklearn.feature_selection?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, svm, multiclass-classification, rfe

I have a dataset of 150 samples and almost 10000 features. I have clustered the samples in 6 clusters. I have used **sklearn.feature_selection.RFECV** method to reduce the number of features. The method estimate the number of important features  3000 features wit  ~95% accuracy using *10-fold CV*. However I can get  ~ 92% accuracy using around 250 features (I have plotted using **grid_scores_**). Therefore, I would like to get that 250 features.

I have checked that question [Getting features in RFECV scikit-learn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50387089/getting-features-in-rfecv-scikit-learn) and found out to calculate the importances of selected features by:

> np.absolute(rfecv.estimator_.coef_)

which returns an array length of number of important features for binary classifications. As i indicated before, i have 6 clusters and **sklearn.feature_selection.RFECV** does classifiacation *1 vs 1*. Therefore i get `(15, 3000)` ndarray. I do not know how to proceed. I was thinking to take dot product for each feature like that:

```
cofs = rfecv.estimator_.coef_

coeffs = []

for x in range(cofs.shape[1]):

    vec = cofs[ : , x]

    weight = vec.transpose() @ vec 

    coeffs.append(weight)
```

And i get array of *(1,3000)*. I can sort these and get the results i want. 
But i am not sure whether it is right and makes sense. I really appreciate any other solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Well i delved into the source code. Here what i found, actually they are doing pretty much same thing:

```
# Get ranks
if coefs.ndim > 1:
    ranks = np.argsort(safe_sqr(coefs).sum(axis=0))
else:
    ranks = np.argsort(safe_sqr(coefs))
```

If it is multi-class problem, they sum up coefficients. Hope that helps others.